# Authenticate Microservice-based API endpoints in Express/Node Js

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication, microservices

I am making a simple microservice-based backend server using express / MongoDB / Node js for ToDo application.

I have one MongoDB database and two separate collections (tables) users and todos

First Microservice is for users with add user, delete user, login (returns JWT Token to the client and store in MongoDB for future verification of private routes), and logout API endpoint (remove JWT token from database).

My second ToDo microservice consists of three routes add, edit, and delete todo and these all are private routes mean they should not be accessible without user authentication.

Following are abstract from both microservices code

**USER Microservice**

**Auth middleware code (decodes token and look in user collection to revalidate the token )**

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')

        const decoded_token = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const user = await Users.findOne({ _id: decoded_token._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user

        next()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please login first.' })
    }
}
```

**Delete current logged in user endpoing**

```
routes.delete('/users/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await req.user.remove()

        res.send(req.user)

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

**Everything above is fine as auth middleware, users schema/model, and user delete endpoint is in my first microservice**

Problem comes below

**ToDo Microservice**

**Add ToDo endpoint**

```
routes.post('/add', auth, async (req, res) => {
     try {
        const todo = new ToDo({
            ...req.body,
            user_id: req.user._id
        })

        await todo.save()

        res.send({ todo })
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

I wanted to use auth middleware on all todo microservice endpoint as I used at delete user endpoint in users microservice.

**Now my question:**
How would I auth any endpoint in any microservice other than user microservice which has all the required stuff but others don't have

**Is it good to rewrite auth middleware code** again in todo microservice as it will redundant the code and secondly even I redundant the code there is no User schema/model in todo microservice?

**Or do I create an auth API endpoint** in users microservice which validates token from the database and returns user object which can be called from any other microservice for user authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to make use of API Gateway in your micro-service architecture.

For example:- you can make use of Kong - https://konghq.com/kong . It comes with it's own PostgreSQL DB as well.

Now let's look at the flow of how requests would work in case of your scenario.

```
Client           |        Middleware          |  User Service             | ToDo Service

1. Logs in ------------------------------------>Authenticates user
                                                generates token
                    <------------------------- saves token in postgres
        <--------------------------------------send token to client

2.Now user hits
  any endpoint ---------->verify the token 
                          with the saved token -------------------------------> GET, POST
                           If yes then hit
                           any service
```

So in short by making use of API gateway, you can implement the JWT authentication structure easily.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. Really appreciated! The scenario you draw is correct and current middleware is where every JWT token must be verified from user collection from mongoDB. You are suggesting to use kong instead of making one extra route in users microservice for authentication?

Comment: I have looked into the kong and trying to implementing it. I have up kong on Kubernetes (Minikube) successfully and now trying to map it to my microservices but still trying to digest their docs :-( and strangely not a single tutorial found for kong with node js express in this huge world of techys :-D If you have any tutorial which I can follow please guide!